# Use PDFDocument properly

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-generation

I can't find any decent sample to use the PDFDocument since API level 19.
The samples mostly show an activity with one text field, and this text field is added to a PDF.

**What I want to do**

I want to subtract data from my models, create a PDF with this data and show this PDF. 
What

**What I don't want**

I don't want to put TextViews and ImageViews in the layout of the fragment, then put these in a PDFDocument and generate a PDF file. 
That seems a bit odd.

**The part I don't get**

Should I create an XML file where I will fill all my views with the data from my models, then create a PDF from this inflated XML? Is het screensize independent?

Please point me in the right direction!

Comment: "Should I create an XML file where I will fill all my views with the data from my models, then create a PDF from this inflated XML?" -- that is impossible to answer in the abstract. If you are really asking "should I create a `View`, independent from what is being shown on-screen, that represents what I want to print?", that may work. However, probably you will need to manually call `measure()` and `layout()` on the root `View` yourself, since a detached `View` is not tied to any window and so will not be measured and laid out automatically.

Comment: I think the most logical workflow for me is: 1. Create an XML 2. Inflate and fill the views of the XML 3. convert that XML to PDF 4. show the PDF in my Fragment. 

Do you have any resources on this workflow?